# How can i loop data in highcharts

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

How do I loop my variable `eNum` inside the `y` data in Highcharts?

I try to use a `for` loop to assign `i` to increment data in the `parseFloat`, but the graph only shows one set of data. Why is this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.extend({
    getValues: function(url) {
      var result = [];
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            result.push(element.revenue);
          });
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  });
  var results = $.getValues("<?php echo base_url('admin_controller/get_data_for_graph') ?>");
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var eNum = parseFloat(results[i]);
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
          name: "Deluxe",
          y: eNum,
        }, ]
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

I just want to loop eNum

```
data: [{
    name: "Deluxe",
    y: eNum,
},]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "Deluxe". Do you want every point to have that same label? Or do you have labels somewhere that could be used for each data point? Or don't you actually need such labels?

Comment: You have included your graph defination inside "for loop". Please take it outside of loop and then give input data as "eNum".

Comment: Deluxe is my example label. i try first eNum to loop data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to call *highchart()* only once per series, not for each data point.

I would suggest first to already convert the data to number with *parseFloat()* in your ajax call, like this:

```
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        result.push(parseFloat(element.revenue));
      });
    }
```

Then you don't need the `for` loop, but can call *highchart* once, like this:

```
var results = $.getValues("<?= base_url('admin_controller/get_data_for_graph') ?>");
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ... all the properties you already have, come here...
    // ...
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: results,
    }]
});
```

The above does not give the data points individual names (labels), as in your question there is only one such label, and it is hard-coded as "Deluxe".

If you want to give that same name "Deluxe" to every point, then you can do that by preparing the *results* array like that in the ajax success callback:

```
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            result.push({
                name: 'Deluxe', 
                y: parseFloat(element.revenue),
            });
        });
    }
```

However, that would seem more useful if you had specific names for each data point, which maybe PHP could provide in the Ajax response.

Comment: it worked.. thank you very much, this is my first time that i use charts for calling json data using ajax php codeigniter thank you again